# a sql query from oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have **two columns(column1, column2)** in my oracle database **table named as demo**. I want to select same column1 having different column2.

```
SQL> select * from demo;

column1 | column2
--------|--------
A       | 10           
A       | 20
A       | 30
A       | 30
```

I want the following output with `count(*)`:

```
column1 | column2
--------|--------
A       | 10           
A       | 20
```

How can i do this? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: You mean if a value in `column1` has different values in `column2` right? Then I presume the third row in your `select *` should be something other than A?

Comment: You can do this using the COUNT operator and the GROUP BY and HAVING constructs

Comment: @jb10210 you are close to right but `other than A means`? I have that above pattern of records in my database

Comment: @saroj: So why do you want to exclude the third row?

Comment: @AmitBhargava can you please little bit clarify? what should be my right query? i have written almost many sorts of sql queries but no result

Comment: @MarkBannister excellent remark because i have to find out same column1 with different values in column2, in third row though same A is present but also with same 30 twice, i have updated my question

Comment: @jb10210 i have updated my question by adding another row `A 30`

Comment: @saroj: Much clearer, thanks - I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @MarkBannister i run your query but output is coming `A   30` but i want `A   10` and `A   20` , anything missing in query, i am trying but unable to find?

Comment: @saroj: I have corrected my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select column1, column2
from myTable 
group by column1, column2
having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: Why would this query lead to the desired output?